# Why the p-value of each parameter in multiple linear regression is mostly less than 0.05?

Tags: python, linear-regression, p-value

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm
from scipy import stats

df = pd.read_csv('new0110_1.csv', encoding= 'unicode_escape')

df=df.dropna(axis=0, how='any')
df_array = df.values
train_group = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15] #all Z
values = df_array[:,train_group] 
reframed = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = 
['Z','T1','T2','T3','T4','T5','T6','T7','T8','T9','T10','T11','T12','T13'])
X,Y = reframed[['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5','T6','T7','T8','T9','T10','T11','T12','T13']] , 
reframed[['Z']]


est = sm.OLS(Y, X)
est2 = est.fit()
print(est2.summary())}
```

[image]

```
df.corr()
```

[image]

The Dependent variable is Z.
The independent variables are [T1、T2.....、T13].

The p-values ​​are all less than 0.05, is it because the dependent variable and the independent variable have a strong correlation?

Comment: You are right. P-value tests the null hypothesis that the coefficient is zero. If the null hypothesis is true then it implies that the tested variable has no impact on the regression.  In your case, the null hypothesis is rejected. Heuristically, the correlation between two variables implies that when one variable changes the value the other changes too. If the dependent variable is correlated with the independent variables it implies that the independent variables will help in the regression task, thus the coefficients are non-zero.

Comment: According to the backward elimination method, p<0.05 will retain the parameters, which means that each parameter has a significant relationship with the dependent variable, so no variables will be eliminate?

Comment: Exactly. No independent variables will be eliminated as they have an impact on the regression task as seen in the correlation matrix or in the p-values results. If the regression task is to find a house price (dependent variable) some aspects of the house (independent variables) such as size or location have a strong impact on the house price. Size and location are correlated with house price, thus they won't be eliminated in the regression. Other aspects of the house such as if the previous owner was bald have 0 impact on the house price. Then 0 correlation and will be eliminated.

Comment: So can't the p-value help to examine the collinearity problem? Because in this case of my experiment, eliminating some variables helps to reduce the average error of training and testing.

Comment: You should use the correlation matrix. Multicollinearity appears when an independent variable is highly correlated with one or more independent variables diminishing the statistical significance of the independent variables. In your example, T1 and T12 are highly correlated with almost every variable then, those independent variables are susceptible to cause the multicollinearity problem. This fact is also captured in the p-value. Multicollinearity implies lower confidence in the p-value test but lower confidence in the p-value test does not imply multicollinearity.

Comment: This means that when the multicollinearity between my independent variables is high, it is actually not suitable to use the backward elimination method to select variables, because the p-value affected by multicollinearity makes the confidence of the p-value test low, and the p-value may all be less than 0.5

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion. What I meant with *"lower confidence"* is that the p-value is higher and this diminishes your confidence on **not** rejecting the null hypothesis in the p-value test. In short, multicollinearity increase the p-value, and thus your confidence in the importance of that independent variable is lower.

Comment: According to (1984 Dillon, W. R. and M. Goldstein: Multivariate Analysis), when the correlation between independent variables reaches above 0.85, there is an obvious threat of collinearity.
Compared with T1, the correlation coefficients of [T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T10, T12, T13] are all higher than 0.85, so they have obvious threat of collinearity with each other.
But the p-value is only T1, and T12 is higher. What is the reason for this?